# Automated ETL of reporting based on 3rd Party Websites

Tags: etl, business-intelligence, data-analysis, data-science

What would be the preferred method to automatically extract reporting which comes from 3rd party customer and supplier websites?

**Additional information:**

- No possibility of direct database connection with these 3rd parties
- No API available for the 3rd party sites
- Each of the 3rd party sites require you to login, set certain reporting criteria and parameters, and then manually export the report to CSV or excel

The end plan is to schedule these reports to be extracted on a certain frequency. The process needs to be automated and should also provide prompts on failures / successful load operations.

I am expecting this to be a highly customised script, but if anyone knows of hosted ETL / Middleware solutions which my solve this, that would be ok as well.

Very interested to hear how we could approach the above problem.

Comment: phantomjs with js script that simulates login and CSV export download?

Comment: Just saying, make sure to check the terms of use of those websites. This probably comes down to [webscraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) which might not always be allowed.

Comment: The websites in reference are suppliers and customers of my business and have fully authorised me to use their data

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko - is there a wesbite which gives me more information around this PhantomJS?

Comment: @WesleyJeftha http://phantomjs.org/documentation/

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko - do you have any experience with PhantomJS? I am wondering if this script can be deployed on a server and automated?

Comment: @WesleyJeftha phantomjs is WebKit-based console utility which is actually fully-functional headless web browser. Actually, it was designed to use on a server and for various automation tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache Airflow.

It is a cron / ETL framework created by AirBnB, based on Python. So with Python scripting you could solve the download problem and Airflow would let you set schedules.

This is just from experience, but: better take a software which helps you with the case than a highly customized script - because eventually, this script will become so complex, it will no longer be maintainable.

Comment: Good comment on the script becoming too complex. I guess there is always a tension between bringing in another 3rd party system vs having full control over a custom script

Comment: Another angle would be: Do we want to expand the loading processes in the future or is this only a small helper tool for another process?